# Enable thread support for Perl in Windows?

Tags: multithreading, perl, parallel-processing, perl-module

I'm trying utilize threads in my Perl script, running on Windows 7. I'm unable to compile the script as Perl wasn't built with thread support when initially installed (the previous user installed Perl without thread support).

How can I rebuild Perl with thread support?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people use ActivePerl or Strawberry Perl on Windows, both of which have thread support enabled.

---

That said, I find it very odd that you have a Perl without thread support on Windows. I think you could be mistaken. You can check if your Perl has thread support by using

```
>perl -v | find "built for"
... for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
```

or more directly with

```
>perl -V:usethreads
usethreads='define';
```

Comment: When I execute the second command, I get:

usethreads='undef';

Comment: "This is perl, v5.8.8 built for msys-64int"
That's my version info.

Comment: @Kratos, Smells like the version of Perl shipped inside `Git Bash`.  You may want to visit either the ActiveState or Strawberry web sites & get yourself a Perl that someone would *want* to use.

Comment: That's not a Windows build of Perl at all. I think msys is a unix emulation environment. Replacing it with a Windows build of Perl may pose compatibility problems. Nothing stops you from having more than one version of Perl installed, though, but you'll have to be sure you use the right one for the right purpose.

Comment: Here's hoping you didn't select the "Run Git and included Unix Tools from the Windows Command Prompt".  That version of Perl is a real albatross.  Those "..included Unix Tools.." also 'bless' you with non-standard `find` and `sort` programs.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether multithreading is supported by your perl or not :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Config;
$Config{useithreads} or die('This perl interpreter does not support execution threads.');
print "This perl interpreter supports multithreading\n";
```